# How to process and save HTTP body as-is in Haskell?

Tags: http, haskell, encoding

I have tried following code to download HTML but it actually transforms non-ASCII characters into series of decoded characters like < U+009B> and 0033200400\0031\0031.

```
openURL x = getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP (getRequest x)

download url path = do src <- openURL url
                     writeFile path src
```

How to change the following code to write HTTP response exactly as received? How should one search and manipulate with strings in such content?

Comment: Can you give a complete example program with an URL that exhibits the behaviour? It would make it easier for others to show you working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string output like "\1234\5678" is actually only two characters long—the data is preserved, but you need to interpret it correctly. Probably the best way to do that is to use `Text` which, instead of being a list of `Char`s, is actually a byte array representing UTF-8 codepoints.

To do this, you need to use a slightly more general interface in HTTP `mkRequest :: BufferType ty => RequestMethod -> URI -> Request ty`. `Text` does not directly instantiate `BufferType`, so we'll go through `ByteString`, which represents binary chunks of data—it has no particular interpretation of the encoding of that data.

We can then use `decodeUtf8` to convert the raw bytes to UTF-8 `Text`

```
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.Encoding
import Data.ByteString

\ uri -> do
  rawData <- getResponseBody =<< simpleHTTP (mkRequest GET uri) :: IO Text
  return (decodeUtf8 rawData)
```

Note that `decodeUtf8` is partial—it may fail in a way that cannot be caught in pure code mandating a restart or handler all the way up in your IO stack. If this is undesirable, if there's a good chance that you're downloading text which isn't valid UTF-8, then you can use `decodeUtf8'` which returns an `Either`.